# Почему js hint не подключается а выдает в терминал ошибку хотя node js я подключил?

Tags: jshint

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Почему js hint не подключается а выдает в терминал ошибку хотя node js я подключил?

Comment: Так в тексте ошибки причина и указана - нет прав на запись в `/usr/local/lib/node_modules`. Самый просто вариант - запустить установку "через `sudo`", самый правильный вариант - разобраться с правами на папку.

Comment: sudo npm install -g jshint
так?

Comment: да, так установка будет происходить с правами супер-пользователя. Есть вариант с переносом папки для глобальных пакетов в домашнюю папку пользователя - [ссылка на англоязычный ответ с SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10081293/install-npm-into-home-directory-with-distribution-nodejs-package-ubuntu/13021677#130216771)

Comment: Спасибо бро за помощь